# how to read rss by self ,not use the rss reader ,

Tags: javascript, rss

I am using Google AJAX Feed to handle the RSS, then I store the data in my database.

but  I encountered a problem :

how to read all  data which updated since last time I read it (and I will lose some items),

thanks

Answer (score 1):

The RSS protocol doesn't support fetching only items since a certain date. Your application must poll for the current version of the feed and check the items in the feed to see if there is anything new. Use the [`guid`](http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/rss/rss.html#hrelementsOfLtitemgt) child-element of the item to uniquely identify items. Ignore all items whose `guid` you have seen before and store those whose `guid` you haven't stored yet.